# Overpass API returning empty response for multiple requests in c#

Tags: c#, overpass-api

Overpass API (https://overpass-turbo.eu/) returning empty response for multiple requests in c#
using HttpClient.

i have also implemented retry functionality.

query i have used for example

[timeout:3600][out:csv("name", ::lat, ::lon;false)]; area["ISO3166-1" = "PE"]; (nodeplace = "village";);out;

Note: if i run the same query in the overpass api directly it is working.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(new RetryHandler(new HttpClientHandler())))
            {

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                Console.WriteLine("Sending request to overpass api - {0}", overPassURL);

                // Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = null;
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for the response from api, Please Wait");

                try
                {


                    var response = client.PostAsync(overPassURL, stringContent);
                    if (response != null && response.Result != null && response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        responseAsString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        return responseAsString;
                    }
                    if (response != null && response.Result != null && !response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return string.Empty;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error(ex.Message);
                    log.ErrorFormat("Stack Trace:{0}, InnerException:{1}", ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException);
                }
                return responseAsString;
            }



public class RetryHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        // Strongly consider limiting the number of retries - "retry forever" is
        // probably not the most user friendly way you could respond to "the
        // network cable got pulled out."
        private const int MaxRetries = 10;

        public RetryHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
            : base(innerHandler)
        { }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < MaxRetries; i++)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("waiting 15 seconds");
                    Thread.Sleep(15000);
                }
                log.InfoFormat("HttpClient SendAsync Trying {0} time", i);

                response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return response;
                }
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
```

I have used  Thread.Sleep(15000); because some times server is busy for returning response

Please help.

Comment: howdy - thx for sharing your ideas and insights- plz do me a favour - can you run this in python too!?